# Sending scheduled mail via Spring Boot Rest api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am fairly new to `spring boot`. I wanna create a spring boot Rest API to send a mail in  preferred - the preferences stored in the **mongoDB**.-  by the user at certain time intervals. But I am very confused about how can I achieve this! Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you have two options:

1. Use Spring capabilities to programmatically schedule the task to the desired date and time. I would suggest you take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M5/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html. Take special attention to the `TaskScheduler` interface;
2. You handle this on your own by checking, from time to time (say every minute), if there are any emails to be sent in that time period.

I would prefer the first one because you would rely on battle-tested features instead of trying to build them on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scheduler cron to call method at some interval or use fixed delay in spring boot @scheduled. and use SMTP method to send message on mail.

```
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 18000)
    public void sendmailviaSMTP() {
      // Code to send message via SMTP
    }
```

Reference:

1. [Scheduling Task](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)
2. [Cron Expressions](https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions)
3. [Send Email with SMTP](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email)

Answer (score 0):

first add **@Scheduled** annotation for your method

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
public void sendMailWithScheduler() {
    //your implementation
}
```

and then add **@EnableScheduling** in your application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class NotificationsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NotificationsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

that's it ! It worked for me !